# Box Rest API: Getting user info after login

Tags: box-api

I know the steps to authenticate user and getting the user info after performing this call:

`GET https://www.box.com/api/1.0/rest?action=get_auth_token&api_key={your api key}&ticket={your ticket}`

But what I'm really looking for is to get user info after performing certain operation such as upload new file, in particular the user quota:

```
<space_amount>1234567</space_amount>
<space_used>1234</space_used>
```

Is there any way to get the latest user quota without calling the 'get_auth_token' again? As I understand it, 'get_auth_token' will generate new auth_token which I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't yet a fully equivalent method in the v2 API. but you can utilize the [get_account_info method](http://developers.box.net/w/page/12923928/ApiFunction_get_account_info) from the v1 API to retrieve this information.